# Error with GET request URL, is it a URL issue or the returned info?

Tags: get, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to retrieve some stuff from a server (can't really go into much detail), but I've run into an issue which is solved by commenting out some stuff in a string being used as the place to hit.

The situation is as follows:

The URL I want to hit is

`http://example.com/api/statistics/installations?version=1.0&type=prod`

I get errors with this (based on the stuff being returned not being as expected), however using this works:

`http://example.com/api/statistics/installations`

Just without the refining flags of `version` and `type`.

Now, I'm new to working alongside servers, so I was wondering if perhaps the first URL is malformed towards the end or something?

Thanks to anyone who answers, even if it's just clarification the URL is correct at least I know where the problem lies afterward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL is fine in that format, the issue was on the other end.